# PHP DOMElement, replacing text of a node

Tags: php, dom

I have a HTML node like so:

```
<b>Bold text</b>
```

A variable $el contains a DOMElement reference to the text of that HTML node ("Bold text"), got from the XPath expression //b/text()

I want to change the element to

```
<b><span>Bold Text</span></b>
```

So I tried:

```
$span = $doc->createElement('span', "Bold Text");
$el->parentNode->replaceChild($span,, $el)
```

which fails because parentNode is null.

So, as a test, I tried:
    $el->insertBefore($span, $el);

which throws no errors but produces no change in the output.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMXPath->query() using  //b/text() should return a DOMNodeList. Get an item using the item() method. It should be a DOMText, which is a DOMNode and parentNode shouldn't be null.

Comment: Thanks, I filed a bug with at php.net, and they appended the SimpleXML documentation to indicate that /text() XPath queries don't return objects in the same format as other queries